# Is it allowed to publish for free a beta version of a program using trial components?

Tags: components, publish, trial

can I offer on my website my program (beta version) for free to test it and searching for bugs when the program contains control components running in trial mode?

I only want to buy the licence when I do the release of the final program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **need to check the licence agreements** for the components. I would suggest contacting the companies/people who supply these as their terms and conditions will vary. In general I suspect the answer is no but you may be lucky.

Comment: I checked several control vendor and they all do not allow it.